# facebook authentication in an ionic app using satellizer

Tags: facebook, ionic-framework

When creating a normal angularjs application that requires facebook authentication, I employ satellizer.

The usual flow is as follows:

```
1. Satellizer brings up facebook authentication window
2. Once authentication information has been entered, satellizer passes the "code" (or token) to the default callback url (which is http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook)
3. At this route, on the server, we query facebook for a long term token and then other details.
```

For the above to work, we setup the application as "web-application" in the facebook-developer-portal.

This has been working successfully for me for several angular web apps.

While developing the ionic app, I followed the same approach:

```
1. Create a web-app in facebook-developer-portal
2. Import satellizer and let satellizer call facebook authentication and pass the token to the callback url(ionic runs on http://localhost:8100 while the callback url is http://localhost:3000)
3. Get the long term token on the server and pass it back to the ionic-app
```

All of the above works FINE as long as I am developing the ionic app in the browser.

However, when I build and run the app in ios emulator, the flow breaks.

When running in the emulator, the app loads. Then satellizer brings up the facebook authentication window. After entering the authentication information, instead of routing to another route, it goes back to login page.

That is to say that the app does not display any other route other than the login route and this would happen only because that app thought that it did not get authenticated.

I am looking for clarity on two issues:

```
1. When running inside an emulator how and where to debug the app ?
2. When runnign insider the emulator, is this still a web-application.
    Does it still bear the adderss http://localhost:8100 ?

   if not, then should I set up this app as mobile-app in facebook developer console ? what other configuration needs to change ?
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with ionic but if you want to implement the FB login in your device without using the FB iOS SDK, you'll have to build the flow manually. Please take a look at this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow I hope it helps.

Comment: hey! @runtimeZero have you find any solution of this problem, i am having error "The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings." i thing i am having same problem